# How do I write an implicit cast for my strongly typed interpreter? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, metaprogramming, interpreter

I'm currently writing an interpreter and it's strongly typed. It has short, int, long, float, and double.
I want to make binary operation between 2 numbers and have an implicit cast.
For example, I want to be able to add an int to a double and return a double, or adding a long to a double and return a double.

The code for the evaulator for a binary expression is written like this

```
std::any Interpreter::visitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression& binaryExpression)
{
    std::any left = binaryExpression.left->accept(*this);
    std::any right = binaryExpression.right->accept(*this);
    Token_t op = binaryExpression.op;

    if (left.type() == typeid(short) && right.type() == typeid(short))
    {
        return eva_num(std::any_cast<short>(left), op, std::any_cast<short>(right));
    }
    if (left.type() == typeid(int) && right.type() == typeid(int))
    {
        return eva_num(std::any_cast<int>(left), op, std::any_cast<int>(right));
    }
    if (left.type() == typeid(long) && right.type() == typeid(long))
    {
        return eva_num(std::any_cast<long>(left), op, std::any_cast<long>(right));
    }
    if (left.type() == typeid(float) && right.type() == typeid(float))
    {
        return eva_num(std::any_cast<float>(left), op, std::any_cast<float>(right));
    }
    if (left.type() == typeid(double) && right.type() == typeid(double))
    {
        return eva_num(std::any_cast<double>(left), op, std::any_cast<double>(right));
    }

    if (left.type() == typeid(bool) && right.type() == typeid(bool))
    {
        return eva_bool(std::any_cast<bool>(left), op, std::any_cast<bool>(right));
    }
    std::string left_err = left.type().name();
    std::string right_err = right.type().name();
    throw std::invalid_argument("Runtime Error: couldn't evaluate type '" + left_err + "' with type '" + right_err + "'");
}
```

The parser generates an AST and then I interpret each statements using the visitor pattern.

The problem is that, since I'm using `std::any` I need to check each scenario for the variable type. And by doing this, I'll end up with more than 100 IF statements, which doesn't sound right.

i tried to replace `std::any` with `std::variant` but i'll still have 100+ if statements.
I tried to use metaprogramming, but i really don't know how to implemenet this (I'm a beginner)

does anyone know how to solve this problem without brutally writing all the if statements?

Comment: It's not clear how you would do that and keep the variables strongly typed like that.  Typically, one uses a `union` for values with one element for each potential type, with an indicator that says what type it is.  Then, you can use a simple table to identify the type promotions that have to happen for a given expression.

Comment: even though i use a `union` for rappresenting a number value, I can't cast a long to int implicitly (Am I right?) and i need to check if operand1 is long && operand2 is int, and then cast them, and then make the binary operation. 

The question is how to "bypass" the amount of if statements that checks whether operand1 is long or int, or double ecc.

Comment: Meta programming happens at compile time, which also would mean your expressions need to be available at runtime. That I think is not going to work

Comment: @Sohryuu Do not use "naked" unions in C++. A lot of people don't know it but they behave a lot different in C++ then they used to behave in "C". And there are a lot of potential undefined behavior scenarios associated with them (active member related).  So unless you know how to used tagged unions... stick with `std::variant`

Comment: Maybe this describes what you are looking for (specially the std::variant part): [Multiple Dispatch in C++](https://belanyi.fr/2022/11/02/multiple-dispatch-in-c-/) : Multiple dispatch on a closed class hierarchy

Comment: You could do "if( type of a is lesser than type of b)" then "a = convert( a, b.typecode )" that would return a new union with the type converted to the type of b.

Comment: @TimRoberts i didn't know I could do that. Could you give me an example with code?

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks a lot, didn't know about multiple dispatch i'll give it a check

Comment: @PepijnKramer if i'm not mistaken, by using multiple dispatch i still need to write all the combination right? That would be the same for if statements though

Comment: Yes you would still need to specify all combinations. But at least you will have moved some of the checking to compile time. (overloads vs. type_id == type_id). Or to put it differently with dispatch you compare on types (compile time) with `if` you compare values (runtime) which helps you find problems sooner (compile time)

Comment: Write down a user guide for your language. Does it say "if the left operand is a double and the right one is an int, then the result is ... otherwise if ..." and so on for 100 lines? Or there is some more sensible formulation?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI what formulation could be out there that replaces all those if conditions? Sorry, this is my first interpreter and i'm a beginner, this might be a stupid question

Comment: If you cannot explain a feature yo your users, perhaps it's not a good feature. Wait, C and C++ have this implicit conversion feature, are you saying that it is no good? Yes incidentally I am, but perhaps you want to look how e.g. a C book (or the language standard) explains it. (Spoiler, they use *conversion rank*, akin to Tim's comment).

Comment: There's no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; it's always explicit. The term you're looking for is "implicit conversion".